# Is there a function for substituting (or removing at all) explaining variables in a linear model (lm)?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I have a linear model with lots of explaining variables (independent variables)

```
model <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + ... + x100)
```

some of which are linear depended on each other (multicollinearity).

I want the machine to search for the name of the explaining variable which has the highest VIF coefficient (`x2` for example), delete it from the formula and then run the old lm function with the new formula

```r
model <- lm(y ~ x1 + x3 + ... + x100)
```

I already learned how to retrieve the name of the explaining variable which has the highest VIF coefficient:

```r
max_vif <- function(x) {
  vifac <- data.frame(vif(x))
  nameofmax <- rownames(which(vifac == max(vifac), arr.ind = TRUE))
  return(nameofmax)
}
```

But I still don't understand how to search the needed explaining variable, delete it from the formula and run the function again.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [`update`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/update) function and paste in the column that needs to be removed. We first can fit a model, and then use update to change that model's formula. The model formula can be expressed as a character string, which allows you to concatenate the general formula `.~.` and whatever variable(s) you'd like removed (using the minus sign `-`).

Here is an example:

```
fit1 <- lm(wt ~ mpg + cyl + am, data = mtcars)
coef(fit1)

# (Intercept)         mpg         cyl          am 
#  4.83597190 -0.09470611  0.08015745 -0.52182463 

rm_var <- "am"
fit2 <- update(fit1, paste0(".~. - ", rm_var))
coef(fit2)

# (Intercept)         mpg         cyl 
#  5.07595833 -0.11908115  0.08625557
```

Using `max_vif` we can wrap this into a function:

```
rm_max_vif <- function(x){
  # find variable(s) needing to be removed
  rm_var <- max_vif(x)
  # concatenate with "-" to remove variable(s) from formula
  rm_var <- paste(paste0("-", rm_var), collapse = " ")
  # update model
  update(x, paste0(".~.", rm_var))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

I created a list containing all variables for `lm` model:

```
Price <- list(y,x1,...,x100)
```

Then I used different way for setting `lm` model:

```
model <- lm(y ~ ., data = Price)
```

So we can just delete variable with the highest VIF from `Price` list.

With the function i already came up the code will be:

```
Price <- list(y,x1,x2,...,x100)

model <- lm(y ~ ., data = Price)

max_vif <- function(x) { # Function for finding name of variable with the highest VIF
  vifac <- data.frame(vif(x))
  nameofmax <- rownames(which(vifac == max(vifac), arr.ind = TRUE))
  return(nameofmax)
}


n <- max(data.frame(vif(model)))

while(n >= 5) { # Loop for deleting variable with the highest VIF from `Price` list one after another, untill there is no VIF equal or higher then 5 
  Price[[m]] <- NULL
  model_auto <- lm(y ~ ., data = Price)
  m <- max_vif(model)
  n <- max(data.frame(vif(model)))

}
```